# Get the Assembly path C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assemblies

Im trying to know the path of a dll.... several sites says that ive to use System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location BUT it returns a path in C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net ... etc... \File.Dll

and i want c:\MyProyect\MiWeb\Bin\File.Dll

any help ?

Comment: Can you post the actual assembly paths that you get, and that you want? Ie. the full paths, with the real assembly names. Also, post the code for the method that tries to determine the assembly path.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
string file = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath;
```

Answer (score 3):

The Location of the assembly changes based on redirects and shadow copy. Try using the Codebase property instead.

Answer (score 1):

That may actually be the path the program is using...  IIRC, It starts out searching for the method call in the GAC before defaulting to the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have referenced the right assembly in your project? Sounds like you are using some "default" assembly since it is located in the .NET folder.