# How to find path to .cs file by its type in C#

Tags: c#

How to find path to .cs file by its type?

Prototype of function:

`string FindPath(Type);`

Returns something like "C:\Projects\.....\MyClass.cs"

Comment: Why do you need this? I'm not sure it is possible at runtime since all code is compiled into an assembly.

Comment: Stop the application (Debug + Stop debugging) and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 33):

In .Net 4.5 you can use the `CallerFilePath` reflection attribute (from MSDN):

```
// using System.Runtime.CompilerServices 
// using System.Diagnostics; 

public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}

// Sample Output: 
//  message: Something happened. 
//  member name: DoProcessing 
//  source file path: c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoCS\CallerInfoCS\Form1.cs 
//  source line number: 31
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This can be used to trace locations of files by doing something along the lines of `public HomeController() : base(TraceFileLocation())` where the base class records the locations. If you're doing it on an instance level you might want to cache the values of `[CallerFilePath]` in a static collection to prevent doing unnecessary work if you're parsing the paths (which i would expect to actually get value out of this)

Answer (score 7):

That's not possible, there is no such relation. A class can be partial, so it can even come from several different source files.

Comment: I'd think it might be possible with a Debug build, because there is enough debugging info stored to show the file name and line number in stack traces (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx).  I'm not sure how to access this info, though.

Comment: @TimS.: The debug information is there, so it's possible to dig it up somehow, but you can only get the source file per statement, not per class.

Comment: Might be slightly outside the scope of the question and this answer, however there is a way to access the information of a PDB via [C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/querying-the-dot-pdb-file?view=vs-2022) that should also allow you to find out where a specific part of a partial class is declared as that'd show up in a stacktrace and thus that information is contained in the pdb.

Answer (score 3):

All classes get compiled in assemblies (.exe or .dll). I don't think you can get the path to the source file of a class, because that class might not even exist (if you have copied the .exe file to another machine).

But you can get the path to the current assembly (.exe file) that is running. Check out this answer: [Get the Assembly path C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/917098/80003)

```
string file = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: This answer should be deleted or converted to a comment.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I disagree, this is a valid answer with relevant information and good explanation why this is not possible.

Comment: Runtime directory is often different from the build/compile directory.  Runtime directory is good to know for file management.  Build directory is good to know for things like branch detection.

Answer (score 0):

If you look within Visual studio, we can directly jump to the source code of a specific type using "Go to Defenition or F12" I believe this is achieved by using Workspace API,  digging more into Workspace API functionality may reveal some solution.

Documentation link here: [Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.workspace?view=roslyn-dotnet)