# Get the path from a SpecFlow feature file in a Step Definition

Tags: c#, specflow

Is it possible to retrieve the path of a SpecFlow feature file during runtime in a Step Definition?

Snippet:

```
[Given(@"Some given statement")]
public void GivenSomeGivenStatement() {

    var featureFilePath = // retrieve the path of the feature file 
                          // that executes this step.
}
```

Context:
We do testing on databases and queries. The source data is created in Excel files and .SQL files (for check queries). These source data are large datasets, not feasible to put into the feature files itself or use the SpecFlow.Plus.Excel extension.
To keep the data close to the feature file, we want to have this data in the same folder as the feature file itself. To achieve this, we need the path to this feature file, so we also have the path to the testdata.

Comment: Seems like a case of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Any chance for some context - what you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: Seems like a test smell to me. Why do you need the path, perhaps there is a better solution to the actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: @decPL Added a context, I hope it is clear what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: are you using NUnit or some other framework as the test framework?

Comment: @SamHolder unfortunately no NUnit. We use MsTest and I use Resharper to run and debug my tests from VS.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a suggestion. This is just something I put together quickly so lots of room to improve. It relies on the Feature file name being identical to the title of the feature you provide in the description. It also assumes you have a conventional folder structure for your SpecFlow VS project as there is a lot of string manipulation.

Firstly, the calling code should use the SpecFlow BeforeScenario attribute. Something like this:

```
public void BeforeScenario()
{      
   //grabs Feature Title from SpecFlow context
   var featureName = FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title;
   //Calls method to obtain path of file
   var featureFilePath = GetFeatureFilePath(featureName);
}
```

The method GetFeatureFilePath will then look like this:

```
private static string GetFeatureFilePath(string featureName)
{
    string startupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory; 
    var splitStartupPath = startupPath.Split(new[] {"\\"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    var featureFolder = splitStartupPath[0] + @"\\" + 
                        splitStartupPath[1] + @"\\" + 
                        splitStartupPath[2] + @"\\" +
                        splitStartupPath[3] + @"\\" +
                        splitStartupPath[4] + @"\\" + 
                        splitStartupPath[5] + @"\\Features\";

    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(featureFolder);

    foreach (var fi in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        if (fi.FullName.Contains(featureName))
            return fi.FullName;
    }

    return "No Feature File Found With Title: " + featureName;
}
```

It grabs your current directory and splits it to the point where the Features folder should be. It then iterates through each feature file until it finds one that contains your feature title in its path name and returns that as a full path.

I'm not aware of any other way to get this currently.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think knowing the path to the feature file will be possible, as the feature file is used to generate a file containing the unit tests and this is compiled and copied to the test run directory.

The simplest thing will be to set the files as part of the solution and then have them copied to the output directory when the project builds.

If you are using NUnit as the test framework then the files should be in the same directory as the tests are executing so you should just be able to load them without specifying any path, or using the [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location(v=vs.110).aspx) to findout where the code is actually executing.

If you are using MSTest then you need to add a `[DeploymentItem(FileToDeploy)]` attribute to the test to ensure that the file actually gets deployed with the tests when they are run. Unfortunately as Specflow generates the tests it won't add this for you. To solve this you need to create a partial class which has the same name as the class which contains the tests. This class is called the same as the feature with 'Feature' tagged on the end. So if you have this in your feature:

```
Feature: Do A Thing
```

The your test class will be called `DoAThingFeature`

so you need to create a partial class like this:

```
[DeploymentItem("FileToDeploy.ext")]
public partial class DoAThingFeature
{}
```

to ensure that MsTest copies the file you need to the correct directory.

**Edit**

based on your comment you could maybe do something similar to this

add tags to your feature `@hasFiles @source:myFile.xlsx`

Then you could add this class:

```
[Binding]
public class DeployFiles
{
     [BeforeScenario("hasFiles")]
     public void CopyFiles()
     {
         ..in here find the current executing directory and search 
         ..the subtree for any files defined in the 
         ..ScenarioInfo.Tags array that start with `source:` and copy 
         ..them to the current executing directory
     }
}
```

then any scenario tagged with the `@hasFiles` will deploy any files specified by `@source` tags to the root directory where the tests are running.

Not pretty and I'm not certain it'll work, but it might.

Comment: Getting data into my output directory is not a problem. By default we have a runsettings.testsettings file under the solution that contains the folders for deployment. The idea was to add a deployment mapping to the folder where the feature files are located.

Comment: then you can just load the files from the current directory can't you? Or am I missing something? Is there a reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: With deployment through the testsettings, the folder structure is also copied. So when one creates a new step in the feature file, he/she must be aware of the folder tree. I want to decouple this and make it dependent on the context. Like the @source:myExcelFile.xlsx tag in the [Specflow.Plus.Excel](http://www.specflow.org/plus/excel/getting-started/) package.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you , in .net 4.5 you can get the hold of the path to the caller, take a look at this thread [source path in .net 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960071/how-to-find-path-to-cs-file-by-its-type-in-c-sharp)