# How can I return C# class file path

Tags: c#

I am attempting to retrieve an individual file path for any given class. For example, I have the class AuthorizeOverrideBalancingPopup.cs in the following filepath:

> C:\development\pom\PageObjectModel\PageObjects\Panel\AuthorizeOverrideBalancingPopup.cs

Are there any C# methods that I can use in order to return that full file path? It seems like most other similar questions return the directory of the IDE instead of the class itself, which is in a completely different directory.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. You have some code in one project that scans the code in another project looking for a particular class, and it should return the absolute path to the file that class is in?

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you want to do this, there might be a better way to solve the problem

Comment: I think your `.cs` files are going to get compiled into a single `.dll` file when you build the project - so the utility of determining the file path of each class might be lost.

Comment: I can elaborate. I want to create a method that returns that test's full path. For instance, I am trying call a function called Utilities.GetClassPath() and that method would return the classes path as a string. I can't seem to figure out how to get the correct path returned in the GetClassPath call.

Comment: Like @alex said, this will all get compiled and you will not have a class path.

Comment: @JonahOberloh but _why_ do you want that?  I can not think of a single reason why this should ever be needed...

Comment: The reason I am looking for this is to then be able to scrape the class name from the path and create a new folder for every given test. The classes that I will be calling this method on are test classes. In the test class folders I am planning on storing multiple screenshots taken on Selenium UI test failures for debugging purposes. The reason I'm asking this question is to have a way to generate the file path for the screenshot method in Selenium and this is the only way that I can think of doing that right now.

Comment: @JonahOberloh Makes sense.  Out of curiosity - is hard-coding the folder names an option?  [Logix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46798764/3474146) might work, but it's scary :P

Comment: I am definitely able to hard code the folder names as an option. I figured that I would ask if there is any way to generate this via a method because as I create a larger library of tests it would get very tedious. I would already have to create over 60 folder names manually if I did it this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find path to .cs file by its type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960071/how-to-find-path-to-cs-file-by-its-type-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [CallerFilePath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetPath());
    Console.Read();
}

static string GetPath([CallerFilePath]string fileName = null)
{
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: This returns exactly what I am looking for. Thank you @logix.

Answer (score 2):

Your program will run somewhere **where those files do not exist**. They are compiled into an `exe` file and are not "shipped" with the code.

The other answer here refers to the code *at compile time* (See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)) and won't be there when the file is executed on the target machine. (Though perhaps that's what you're looking for?)

**EDIT according to your comment** ("to then be able to scrape the class name")

use `this.GetType().Name` or `typeof(Class1).Name` or `nameof(Class1)` [from C# 6]

Comment: Your edit also returns the portion that I was looking for, I really appreciate your help. Thanks @ispiro!