# Find .cs file path from any given type in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

The attribute `[CallerFilePath]` seems to do what I need to do:

[How to find path to .cs file by its type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960071/how-to-find-path-to-cs-file-by-its-type-in-c-sharp/22148801#22148801)

...but I would like to be able to avoid having to add this new prop to every type that I want to check:

```
public string SourceFilePath { get; } = Helper.GetCallerFilePath();
```

What I have tried:

- Adding this method at runtime does not seem to be an option.
- Using it in a base class does not seem to work either (it returns the
  path of the base class).

My guess is that this is somehow feasible, because an exception is able to give you this kind of info (from any given type).

---

What I really want to do in my particular case is: I have a set of cs files that can be identified via their implemented interface, and I want to know their location in the file structure of the project.

So in this case I don't need to know the file location of *any* given type, but it would be my preferred approach if that's possible.

Comment: What if it is a partial class?

Comment: Why do you need the path to the code file at all? When compiled, .cs files no longer exist.

Comment: First of all, class =/= file. A file may contains several class and a class can be split in several files (partial classes). Nor extension method nor StackTrace will help you since you don't want to add code IN your file. I think the example of Exception is not relevant since it is able to give the file where the code were executed (and you don't want to execute code in each file).

Comment: However, if your files architecture match your class architecture (1 subfolder = 1 subnamespace and 1 file = 1 class), I guess you can create an extension method that get param.GetType().FullName and parse it to compose the filename.

Comment: The goal is to auto-generate a documentation (<summary> tag, plus other documentable things that I can get via reflection). The .cs files that I want to scan are in subfolders, BUT they are do not match the subfolder<->namespace convention. This is why I wanted to find a reasonable way to fetch the "folder classification", so I can classify the retrieved documentation.